# Как добавить фоновую музыку в игру на Windows Forms C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, разработка-игр, аудио

В игре уже есть другие звуки, но они связаны с конкретными действиями пользователя. При запуске игры фоновая музыка играет, но как только включаются другие звуки, фоновая музыка сразу же прерывается и больше в ходе игры не включается. Ожидалось, что она будет играть независимо от других звуков.
Звуки я добавляю с помощью **SoundPlayer** используя System.Media. Например:

```
SoundPlayer sound_main = new SoundPlayer(@"D:\12.wav");
        sound_main.PlayLooping();
```

*Пробовала* включать фоновую музыку в загрузке формы - все тоже самое.
*Пробовала* использовать **Windows Media Player** (предварительно добавив ссылку на библиотеку в проект). Код нашла в инете.

```
public WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer WMP = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

        WMP.URL = @"sound.mp3" // файл музыкальный
        WMP.settings.volume = 100; // меняя значение можно регулировать громкость
        WMP.controls.play(); // Старт
        WMP.controls.stop(); // Стоп
        WMP.close();
```

Все строки, кроме первой подчеркивает красным и пишет что нет такого в текущем контексте.

Comment: Подчеркнутые строки надо а метод засунуть.

Comment: Есть такая библиотека NAudio, доступна в NuGet, поизучайте.

Answer (score 0):

Ой то есть я ваш код использовал как другие короткие звуки как ходьба. А фоновый звук сделал

```
private SoundPlayer Player = new SoundPlayer();
this.Player.SoundLocation = @"C:\..\fon_music.wav";
this.Player.PlayLooping();
```

У меня была проблема с этой фоновой музыкой, благодаря вашему вопросу и способа вашего решения я смог сделать фоновый звук. Если вы еще не нашли свою ошибку то WMP.URL = @"sound.mp3" вы забыли ; точку запятую. И желательно уберите

```
WMP.controls.stop(); // Стоп
WMP.close();
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоил дополнить этим ваш предыдущий ответ, а этот удалить. или наоборот.